# Date to serial number?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

What I Have:

In A column i have id numbers and in B column i have date(mm-dd-yyyy).

What I want:

In c column I want is Id/yy.
example: 1231/18

I did try using the =CONCATENATE(A1,"/",TEXT(YEAR(B1),"yy"))
its giving #value error.

Comment: do you require leading zeroes for ids less than 1000? e.g. 0123/18

Answer (score 0):

You can use =CONCATENATE(A1,"/",YEAR(B1))
Please check the format of enter date in B1 COLUMN.

Comment: How are you entering date?

Comment: concatenate(1231,"/", year(9/22/2018)) like this

Comment: Use CONCATENATE(1234,"/",YEAR(22-09-2018))

Comment: You are entering date in wrong format. Check the column corresponding to date for input format. To check right click on the column and click on format

Comment: =CONCATENATE(A2,"/",RIGHT(B2,FIND("/",B2,6)-4)) thsi what i looking for i try my self.

Answer (score 0):

You've provided very little sample data so I will just assume worst-case scenarios for all data elements and attempt error control on each.

```
=CONCATENATE(TEXT(A1, "0000;@"), "/", TEXT(IFERROR(DATEVALUE(B1), B1), "yy"))
```

If you don't require leading zeroes for IDs being less than 4 digits, change the first TEXT format mask from `"0000;@"` to `"0;@"`.

In the following sample image, note that only the top date is a true date; the bottom two are text that look like dates. Likewise, A2 holds text that looks like a number.

[image]